# I am unable to get back the file I saved after exiting from the Klee

Tags: c, terminal, ubuntu-18.04, klee, symbolic-execution

I am researching symbolic execution based on the klee tool. I am running klee via docker. I create a directory and save c program file in that directory. But after exiting from klee, and again If I try to enter back into the klee, it shows that there is no such directory and the program which I saved was lost. Please, help me to solve this.Hope you will help. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the problem. The problem was that I have removed the container after saving the files. I have used the following command before.

```
$ docker run --rm -ti --ulimit='stack=-1:-1' klee/klee
```

This consists of `rm` which removes the container. That's why while removing the container, the directory and saved files got deleted. To solve this issue,we have to create a container and save your files in that container. Don't remove the container. Following are the steps I have followed:

1. Create a docker container.Give the name of the Container you want to create. The name of my container is `my_first_klee_container`.

```
$ docker run -ti --name=my_first_klee_container --ulimit='stack=-1:-1' klee/klee
```

2. Now you can create a directory and type a c program and save it.
3. Compile using llvm compiler and run it using klee.
4. now exit from the klee by typing exit command.
5. Try to restart your container by the following command:

```
$ docker start -ai my_first_klee_container
```

6. Type the command `ls`. Now, you can see and access the files you have created.

For more information, visit https://klee.github.io/docker/

Comment: Note that you can mark your answer to your own question as accepted.